# bootstrap selectpicker isn't adding last selected item in array when we get value using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-selectpicker

i am using bootstrap selectpicker to get multiple values in my ajax call but when i try to get value using jquery .val() function it gives me an array but the last selected is missing in that array. below is my code with figures for more understanding

```
 <label class="selected_types">Property Type :</label>
 <select id="sidebar-adv_categ" class="form-control selectpicker1" multiple data-live-search="true">
 <option value="all"> All </option>
 <option value="industrial"> Industrial </option>
 <option value="office"> Office </option>
 <option value="retail"> Retail </option>
 </select>
```

when i select 1st value it returns me an empty array, and when i select 2nd or 3rd value it returns me the 1st one but not last one i selected.

here is how i am getting it in my ajax call using jquery

```
 category        =   jQuery('#sidebar-adv_categ').val();
```

Comment: Can’t reproduce, with the example under https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes, `$('#multiple-select-boxes + div .selectpicker').val()` typed into the browser console gets me _exactly_ what I selected each and every single time.

Comment: it returns me undefined ?

Comment: Don’t know what else to tell you, works fine for me, in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: sure thanks for your help

Comment: show your event handler .